# Can we have a language other than English in a URL?

Tags: php, url, character, hindi

I know the answer to my question is Yes, But I am really interested to know how its done with my application in PHP. I am basically looking for a URL that contains Hindi characters.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve. If I understand your question correctly, you want me to show you a URL with hindi characters, is that right? If not, can you please put it in context and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: <a href="बॉलीवुड.com">बॉलीवुड.com</a> ????

Comment: It is all about browser's support. If browser supports that - you can just use it as-is, but if doesn't - user will see `%dddd`-encoded string

Comment: @Francois, yes I think you understand my question correct. @Dagon, I know I could register a domain encoded in hindi, my question was specific to the later part of the URL @zerkms, yes I think that's right. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatly, [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396) says you're not allowed to use any non alphanumeric characters. You can however encode them, but that defeats your point of having nicely 'speaking urls'.

Comment: Oh I see. I understand what you say. So, you mean I could have a URL like www.abcd.com/बॉलीवुड but it wouldn't be SEO-friendly at all, isn't it? Also I understand this wouldn't be user-friendly either, LOL at my silly question!

Comment: not quite. The url www.abcd.com/बॉलीवुड would be invalid, whereas www.abcd.com/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%89%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A1 would be valid (that's the encoded version of बॉलीवुड). But that's not more readable/SEO friendly than any other URL

Answer (score 1):

ICANN (The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers) exists with the sole responsibility of managing top-level domain name systems and IP addresses

a translation system needs to be created that allows multiple scripts to be converted to the right address. ICANN is also to decide on the degree of freedom given on global top-level domain names. Right now, web addresses can only be chosen from 21 suffixes such as .net or .com. If this changes companies and individuals can have unlimited choices such .indian / .delhi or maybe an anshul.jain