# There is no % mark in the decoded URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I own a Wordpress site in Persian language. Recently I have noticed that certain requests to some of my posts get a 404 error, because the URL does not get correctly encoded in their browsers. For example, if the url of the post is

http://mywebsite.com/**مثال**

when a visitor wants to visit that post, for a strange reason, they a 404 page as the url is encoded as

http://mywebsite.com/**D985D8ABD8A7D984**

which does not have the **%** mark in it. In other words, the correctly encoded url should include the following after the domain name:

**%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84**

Please let me know if the problem is on my side or the visitors' behalf.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Unfortunatly, RFC2396 says you're not allowed to use any non alphanumeric characters. You can however encode them, but that defeats your point of having nicely 'speaking urls'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515781/can-we-have-a-language-other-than-english-in-a-url

Comment: Hello Bender. Thanks for responding. So you mean the visitor gets the 404 page because I have used non alphanumeric characters (i.e. Persian language letters) in the url? Actually, when I myself test that page with major browsers it gets correctly encoded and shows the post correctly and the non alphanumeric characters are also displayed finely in the url. It seems to be only problematic for some visitors.

Comment: It is all about browser's support mostly language i guess. If browser supports that. since you can see those Persian chars . user from UK or USA might not parse that url since browser support

Comment: i'll suggest not to use url rewrite

Comment: which means not having clean urls, right?