# iis has bug on persian name folders?

Tags: php, iis, php-7.4

I config PHP 7.4.5 in IIS 10.0, 
and when I rename a folder to Persian characters like: "تست", and try to access the page with this address :

```
http://mydomain/تست/
```

it can not find index.php,
and show this error :

```
No input file specified.
```

after renaming to the English letter: "test", the url is:

```
  http://mydomain/test/
```

everything is ok!

> Hint: if the folder name has Persian chars, all good with index.html 
> Hint: My handler Mapping :
>  [image]

**what I try to solve the problem:** 
I try to change this vars in php.ini but not solve my problem.
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
cgi.force_redirect = 0

Comment: open the php.ini file and set the following option:`cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`

Comment: i do, but not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue is not related to the iis its related to the PHP. below is the test with the HTML site which is working correctly:

[image]

Unfortunately, [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396) says you're not allowed to use any non-alphanumeric characters. You can however encode them, but that defeats your point of having nicely 'speaking URLs'.

Reference link:

[Can we have a language other than english in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515781/can-we-have-a-language-other-than-english-in-a-url)